# Including .hpp files in CMakeLists.txt for a Multi DIR Project?

Tags: c++, cmake

### Problem:

I am struggling to link the header files in the project correctly using CMake lists. All the example online seem to be simpler and the projects use "Modern CMake" with relations which I'm also unfamiliar with.

### Error:

*warn*

XXXXX.hpp is not a directory

*fatal error*

#include XXXXX.hpp: No such file or directory

**Back Ground Statement:**
The root dir is a node within a larger ROS based project utilising catkin tools. It is a Unix system Ubuntu 20.04. I will replicate the system directory using generic titles below, it will include all build related files ( I can expand where necessary upon request ).

### File sys:

[image: File Sys Diagram]

**Details of CMakeLists.txt**

root_dir/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(project_name LANGUAGES CXX)



add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/orange ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/orange)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/project_name_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
    orange-lib
)
```

root_dir/include/project_name/orange/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(orange-lib navel.cpp blood.cpp tangelo.cpp)

// as per Friedrich suggestion
include_directories(orange-lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/project_name/orange)
```

Comment: BTW, you should have the `project` command once per project, not in every CMakeLists.txt and consider using `target_include_directories(orange-lib PUBLIC relative/path/to/include_dir)`. Also, you don't need to `set` variables you only use once.

Comment: Thank you for that i did wonder if project commands are global in that regards. The set() was in there are as I am trying to reduce a larger directory into a smaller working version. I.e. get the basic functionality then reimplement more complicated code. Can you explain what this line is and where it would be defined in my context?
target_include_directories(orange-lib PUBLIC relative/path/to/include_dir)

Comment: I posted an answer demonstrating the use of `target_include_directories`.

Comment: Please don't change your question based on the answers you receive. This will make it impossible for future readers to understand what the question is about. If you find a solution yourself, you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root_dir/include/project_name/orange/CMakeLists.txt should be

```
project(project_name LANGUAGES CXX)


set(INCLUDE_DIRS
    /full/path/to
)

set(CXX_SRCS
    navel.cpp
    blood.cpp
    tangelo.cpp
)


add_library(orange-lib ${CXX_SRCS})

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

You don't want to provide the full path to the file as include directory, but the path to the parent directory `/full/path/to`. In your cpp file you then can use

```
#include "navel.hpp"
#include "blood.hpp"
#include "tangelo.hpp"
```

Comment: I believe this fixed my problem one follow up is calling said include headers inside the project_name_node.cpp. how would I define that. Do i need to access this through the library or do something inside the CMakeLists. Is this where PUBLIC is used?

Comment: This is not a modern cmake. This pattern is old and should not be used anymore.

Comment: If I'm trying to access navel.hpp from project_name_node.cpp, what should occur so that it's in line with modern CMake given that with the above implementation,

#include "rel/path/to/navel.hpp" through a No such file or directory fatal error? I can adjust the question prompt to reflect this new line of questioning if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Your `root_dir/include/project_name/orange/CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
add_library(orange-lib)
set(public_headers_path <directory where public headers are>)
target_sources(orange-lib
    navel.cpp
    blood.cpp
    tangelo.cpp
    ${public_headers_path}/navel.hpp
    ${public_headers_path}/blood.hpp
    ${public_headers_path}/tangelo.hpp 
)

target_include_directories(orange-lib PUBLIC ${public_headers_path})
```

Part of the problem is that your directory structure is badly designed. `include/...` should start from same level as respective `CMakeLists.txt` and you have to reach to parent directory.

Comment: I really think the `project` command should not be in there. Especially as it duplicates the "project_name" already set in the project root's CMakeLists.txt. Is this an oversight or am I missing something, here?

Comment: Agree. I just cop paste that and focused on main issue.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can throw a lot of superfluous code out of `root_dir/include/project_name/orange/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# no project() here, it suffices to have it once

# just use the source file names
add_library(orange-lib navel.cpp blood.cpp tangelo.cpp)
# could also use a relative path below
target_include_directories(orange-lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/project_name/orange)
```

See the documentation of [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) for reference.

In fact, we should be able to do without `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`. An alternative would be to just give the relative path (including `..` to go up some levels). Or consider putting `orange-lib`'s includes next to the sources.

Comment: The comments above have resolved the post in the initial question however in the project_name_node.cpp All the include headers are not found. I think that something is wrong then with the linking for the executable?

Comment: Not found as in "you get a compiler error" or not found as in "your IDE shows nothing"? For the IDE part, you'd have to add the header files as well as Marek R does. If something's wrong with the linking, you'd get a *linker error* and you didn't write any such thing in your question.

Comment: Upon catkin bto, I get No such file or directory ... compilation terminated make[2] *** make [1] ***. in my IDE the #includes have red lines under them, saying please update your include path. The tried has been include/project_name/orange/navel.hpp,  navel.hpp and other vairants

Comment: You can print the paths using e.g. `message(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/project_name/orange)` and check they match the paths on your drive. I know only what's in the picture you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think if I am to revieve further help I would need to review how I ask the question from here so I can provide more context. I have checked the path and it seems to be what i expected. it's failing to recognise 3rd party downloads such as OpenCV ect... as well as these internal libs such as orange-lib, as related headers